# VB.net .replace start and end of string

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I use this to dynamically place the system variable of `URL` as the class on the body. The problem is that it strips the first trailing '/' and replaces it with a hyphen, which is annoying.

How could I prevent this and just replace the first '/' with nothing?

**VB**

```
<body class="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL").Replace(".aspx","").Replace("/","-")%>">
```

At the moment if I use:

```
<body class="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL").Replace(".aspx","").Replace("/","")%>">
```

I get something like 'userprofileedit' from a URL of /user/profile/edit

What I actually want is 'user-profile-edit' as a class on my body instead of 'userprofileedit'. My first example:

```
<body class="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL").Replace(".aspx","").Replace("/","-")%>">
```

Does what I need, however I then get a starting hyphen due to the first / from '/user..' - hope this better explains my problem.

Comment: Add the '/' back on afterwards?

Comment: Updated to try explain a little more

Comment: Is the / the first character? You could remove it: Request.ServerVariables("URL").Replace(".aspx","").Remove(0, 1)   I would highly suggest you put that logic in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Substring(1)` to get everything but the first character:

```
<body class="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL").Substring(1).Replace(".aspx","").Replace("/","-")%>">
```

Note: The approach of using `Replace` to remove the `.aspx` from the page would also remove it from a folder if it would happen to contain that, but as long as you are aware of that and don't name the folders that way, you're safe.

Comment: Is this technically a better way of doing it over the .remove() method above?

Comment: @Mat-visual: The difference is very small, but the `Substring` method is a bit simpler as it gets one part of the string, while the `Remove` method concatenates two parts of the string (the part  before and after the range that you specify).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Remove function to strip off the first character:

```
<body class="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL").Replace(".aspx", "").Replace("/", "-").Remove(0, 1)
```